# What is rotor torque in the stepping motor context?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, torque

I have the following datasheet for a stepping motor.

[image]

I am wondering what "Rotor Torque" means in the stepping motor context. My first guess would be the torque produced by the rotor under normal electrical specifications, but the unit used for this is g*cm^2, which I don't think translates to the Newton-meter. Hence, my uncertainty.

The full datasheet: https://www.pololu.com/file/0J635/SY20STH30-0604A.pdf

Please let me know if more information is required. For context, I am trying to change the rotational speed of a load connected to the stepper motor by changing the power, and I need the value of the torque to make accurate calculations.

Comment: Loose wording, likely: look at the units. Rotational moment of inertia?

Comment: on the one hand, the other things they call torques have the right units, so the units could be a typo. On the other, the values for holding torque and rotor are so far apart that the units could be right and they mean rotor moment of inertia.